# Questions about dual booting and brand new SSD!

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, ssd

I am new to Linux (besides briefly messing around with it over 10 years ago) and I have some questions about setting up dual boot with Windows 7. Basically I am looking for the best way to get up and running so if you have other suggestions that would be better than what I list below please let me know!

So my new SSD just came about 5 minutes ago so I'll be installing that today as my boot drive. My "plan" was to install Windows 7 from my USB first and get that all set up and then after all that, partition the SSD and install Ubuntu. Is there any downside to doing it this way? Once Windows is set up do I just use the built in "Disk Management" to partition the drive or when I boot from the Ubuntu installer is there an option there to partition the drive similar to how there is when going through windows setup?

This might not be directly related but is there anything special I need to do to this new SSD before installing windows? It's my first SSD. Should I connect it as a second drive first and use Windows "Disk Management" to format it? OR just install it as my main drive and get right to installing windows? Or should I install it as my second drive and partition it first thing with Disk Management?

As you can see I'm not sure of the best ways to set this all up or if it even really matters. Any input would be appreciated of what is the best way to go about this and why it's better than another way.

Thank you!!

Comment: The Windows installer allows you to partition the disk during installation, it is one of the first steps. Everything is easier if you install Windows first, leaving enough free space for Ubuntu, and then install Ubuntu in the free space. How to plan operationally the installation(s) is of course up to you. Some SSD vendors provide easy migration programs which aim to copy your existing Windows installation to your new SSD.

Comment: So is system UEFI or BIOS? Most Windows 7 systems are BIOS boot with MBR partitioning, only a few released just before Windows 8 or downgrades of Windows 8 are UEFI. Windows normally will use entire drive. Just use Windows to shrink the NTFS partition to make room for Ubuntu, but do not create partitions with Windows. You can partition in advance with gparted, use auto install that only gives / (root) & swap or create partitions during install with Something Else.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I just got finished with the windows install I started it before I saw your reply. I did exactly what you mentioned and just installed Windows normally. Updates are finishing installing now. So your saying I don't even need to free up some space with disk Management in Windows? I just boot from the Ubuntu USB and it will allow me to reduce the Windows partition and create a new one?  I thought I saw something on reddit saying that it was better to create the partition in Windows.. something about the Ubuntu tool not working as good? I don't remember.

Answer (score 0):

Completely Install windows on the entire drive, don't worry about partitioning at all, use the entire drive, after you have rebooted and installed updates and are happy with the results, you can download a Linux distro such as Ubuntu. Download and burn .iso to blank DVD disk or make a LIVE USB using - unetbootin - Then install Ubuntu using the Live desktop that you boot to.  During the install you will have a screen that will ask you if you want to erase disk and install Ubuntu or install Ubuntu alongside Windows. You want to click the check for install alongside Windows. Live desktop installer in Ubuntu will take care of all the partitioning for you :-) All Done ENJOY Using LINUX :-)  If you want to check out some COOL Linux distro's go here>          http://distrowatch.com/      Go to right side of page and there are listings from the #1 distro to #100 in ranking. ENJOY